# Edit the final part of large(1.5gb) text file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, readline, large-files

My tool appends little json blocks with comma at their end into a txt file which initially has `[` as the first character, in order to create a whole JSON format text file, like below,

```
{data: text1},
```

and txt file seems like at the end of the day,

```
[{data: text1},{data: text2},{data: text3},
```

So I have to remove last comma at the end of the text and put a `]` to make it valid JSON right, but this file size is around 1.5GB so I couldn't figure how to edit it in NodeJS in order to make it valid JSON file.

Comment: A better question might be why you have a 1.5gb JSON file that requires dynamic updates. What about a database solution, or splitting the file up? If this is essentially logging, then you could use a format that doesn't require a trailing `]`, or a command-line tool that would allow you to append to the file (while truncating the last `n` bytes).

Comment: I have an idea, don't really know if it can be implemented. If every character is fixed size and if there is something like `seek` operation when reading file, maybe you can seek to end of file minus 2 * size of character and then write `]` and delete rest of it if needed.

Comment: Hi @Rogue, thanks for interest, my browser extension bot is actually pushing the json blocks all the time into that txt files through my browsing activities and I process them on NodeJS at the end of the day but overtime the data gets bigger so maybe I should switch to some beter db logics after that but I am still tryna find a way to keep in txt file as long as I could work with it if possible coz the data collected there is meant to be deleted after I process them with nodeJS

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I am also thinking to target somehow the last line of the chunk in order to make the difference on final part of whole text, every json blocks pushed to txt file has diff length btw

Comment: I guess you are using UTF-8, not ASCII, right?

Comment: yeah UFT-8, actually found a way to update whole file as I wanted, but now I cannot parse this 1.5GB valid JSON file 

Comment: Ohh, ok, didn't see your comment before I posted my answer. What do you mean you can't parse it? Because of size or...?

Comment: I do question where all this data is going. If where it is going can handle the load, then why not send the data there directly? If you're pumping 1.5gb of data a day into this file, you're left with a couple options. 1) Rotate the file more frequently, e.g. on an hourly basis. 2) Abandon JSON, use a more compact format (could just be each chunk of text with a separating character like `\n` or `\0`).

Comment: @MilosStojanovic UTF-8 encodes ASCII as a single byte anyhow. If the OP requires multi-byte characters, then ASCII likely wasn't an option to begin with.

Comment: @Rogue Yeah, I got it in the end. Google was my friend :).

Comment: Yeah @Rogue, I used to use `\n` at the end solution on my similar tools before but this one developed somehow with this dirty method  and I didn't wanna break it since it's working good,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Input and output file paths
const inputFile = 'input.json';

// Open the file for reading and writing
fs.open(inputFile, 'r+', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error opening the input file:', err);
    return;
  }

  // Move to the end of the file
  fs.fstat(fd, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error reading file information:', err);
      fs.close(fd, () => console.log('Closed the input file due to error.'));
      return;
    }

    const endPosition = stats.size;

    // Create a buffer for reading
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1); // Read only one byte (comma)

    // Read the last byte in the file
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, endPosition - 1, (err, bytesRead, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error reading the last byte:', err);
        fs.close(fd, () => console.log('Closed the input file due to error.'));
        return;
      }

      // Check if the last byte is a comma
      if (data[0] !== 44) { // Unicode code for comma is the same as ASCII
        console.log('The last character is not a comma.');
        fs.close(fd, () => console.log('Closed the input file.'));
        return;
      }

      // If the last byte is a comma, replace it with a closing bracket
      const closingBracket = Buffer.from(']', 'utf8'); // Use UTF-8 encoding
      fs.write(fd, closingBracket, 0, closingBracket.length, endPosition - 1, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error writing to the file:', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Replaced the comma with a closing bracket.');
        }
        // Close the input file
        fs.close(fd, () => console.log('Closed the input file after modification.'));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works really fast. Any recommendation about how to parse this large file on NodeJS, tried `JSONStream ` and `big-json` packages but both returned `Error: Unexpected RIGHT_BRACKET("]") in state KEY` error even though the JSON was valid,

Comment: If the problem occurs because the `json` file is too large and the library cannot parse it because of its size, the only thing that comes to mind is to iterate through the file and parse parts of the file separately according to some criteria (new line or something similar).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Milos, anything comes to mind about how to split this equally maybe 3-4 parts without breaking the structure, maybe can target some comma's in the middle of chunk for split point

Comment: Is there always only one root array that contains objects with key named data and value that is always string? Meaning there will never be any nested objects?

Comment: That's part of my real JSON structure, https://gist.github.com/rainb3rry/ae8bd8d8b9241a97675862e393c9678d

Comment: Guess I gotta figure how to split this to equal parts before parsing them

Comment: I would suggest reading equal chunks of file, add it to buffer, applying regex on buffer to check if it's valid json object. If it is, parse it and find where it ends so you can slice buffer so it starts where you ended parsing so that part of data you didn't parse stay in buffer and then add next chunk and keep doing it until you get to end of file. Don't forget to then check if there is some data you didn't parse in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Additional solution for updating large-sized files with `Transform` as you wanted but working slower than Milos's code for my specific situation,

```
const fs = require('graceful-fs');
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const sourceFilePath = 'jsfiles.txt';
const destinationFilePath = 'new.txt';

// Create a transform stream to modify the data
const transformStream = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        // Modify the data as needed
        var modifiedData = chunk.toString().slice(0, -1); // remove last comma
        this.push(`${modifiedData}]`); // add last closing bracket
        callback();
    }
});

// Create a readable stream from the source file
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });

// Create a writable stream to the destination file
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });

// Pipe the data through the transform stream before writing to the destination file
readStream.pipe(transformStream).pipe(writeStream);

// Handle events when the copying is complete
readStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('File duplication completed.');
});

writeStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Data has been written to the destination file.');
});

// Handle errors during the process
readStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error reading from the source file:', err.message);
});

transformStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error transforming data:', err.message);
});
```